# How to assert that mocked method is never called using ScalaTest and ScalaMock?

Tags: unit-testing, scala, mocking, scalatest

I'm using ScalaTest 2.0 and ScalaMock 3.0.1. How do I assert that a method of a mocked trait is called never?

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalamock._
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory

class TestSpec extends FlatSpec with MockFactory with Matchers {

  "..." should "do nothing if getting empty array" in {
    val buyStrategy = mock[buystrategy.BuyStrategyTrait]
    buyStrategy expects 'buy never
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two styles for using ScalaMock; I will show you a solution showing the Mockito based style of Record-Then-Verify.  Let's say you had a trait `Foo` as follows:

```
trait Foo{
  def bar(s:String):String
}
```

And then a class that uses an instance of that trait:

```
class FooController(foo:Foo){  
  def doFoo(s:String, b:Boolean) = {
    if (b) foo.bar(s)
  }
}
```

If I wanted to verify that given a false value for the param `b`, `foo.bar` is not called, I could set that up like so:

```
val foo = stub[Foo]
val controller = new FooController(foo)
controller.doFoo("hello", false)
(foo.bar _).verify(*).never
```

Using the `*`, I am saying that `bar` is not called for any possible String input.  You could however get more specific by using the exact input you specified like so:

```
(foo.bar _).verify("hello").never
```

Comment: ScalaMock 3 (which you use here) requires ScalaTest 2.0.M5b--a beta version for which I can't find any documentation, and seems to break my existing tests. Is there something I'm doing wrong here? I'm closing to using ScalaMock 2 instead.

Comment: Is it possible to do something in between `*` and and a particular value, using e.g. `mockFunction`? If so I didn't see how

Answer (score 0):

If you use expectations-first style, this is actually the default for any methods that you don't explicitly set expectations for. So you don't need to do anything. However, as a general point, you must not reuse mocks between tests that have different expectations - that won't work - rather, you must create a new mock for each test.